# How can I export the saved wireless networks in Win7?

Tags: windows-7, password-management, wireless-networking

I am about formating my computer. I would like to know whether is possible to export all saved wireless networks and restore them back. I have about 50, mostly from clients, and I don't want to mark passwords or something.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In command prompt type the following to view all your wireless profiles:

```
netsh wlan show profiles
```

Next for each profile that you want to export run the following command, I would suggest saving to a USB drive or network share. Just make sure it's something secure because you don't want people stealing your clients wifi information.

```
netsh wlan export profile name="network-name-here" folder="d:\destination"
```

Finally on the computer where you want to add the profiles run the following command to import from the USB pen or network share.

```
netsh wlan add profile filename="d:\source.xml"
```

I would suggest testing out the commands first, before formatting, just to make sure they work for you and there are no supprises after the format.

Answer (score 2):

you could just type

```
netsh wlan export profile folder="c:\destination"
```

and that will put them all in a folder named "destination" on your c: